# Django- Reverse for 'question_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found

Tags: python, django

When I type the slug in to the url I can see the detail view of that post however, I can't redirect to the newly formed post when it saves into db. 
The post's are getting saved but on the redirect I keep getting NoReverseMatch Error.

`Reverse for 'question_detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(?i)question/(?P<slug>[\w\\-]+)/$']`

I can't seem to crack it.

questions-url.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)/$', QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='question_detail')
```

views- redirect (after form saved) :

```
return reverse('questions:question_detail')
```

views - detail view

```
class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
template_name = "questions/question_detail.html"
model = Question
slug_url_kwarg = 'slug'
```

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('questions:question_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug, 'question_id':self.id})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the `question_detail` pattern expects a slug parameter but you are not passing one. You do so in your get_absolute_url method; you should do the same in your view.

Comment: the error actually says "1 pattern(s) tried: [u'(?i)question/(?p<slug>[\w\\-]+)/$'])". I'm not sure why it won't come up on the question. Unless you mean passing a slug parameter in my view in another way

Comment: Yes that's what I said. You're not passing that slug kwarg in your call to reverse.